# Does switching from specific domain extension to the TLD domain affects the overall SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, ranking, top-level-domains

I had the domain extension that ends from .in and after a year I changed it to .com. So I wanna know if this whole process severely affects the SEO. I'm still ranking well in India but that's not what I want, It should rank elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you 301 redirect your .in pages to the new ones on .com.

.com is considered a general domain which could be associated with any region. You can control this in Google Search Console under the legacy tool of "international targeting" then the Country tab.

Opinion is that there is no real negative global impact on targeting a country.